# A Lua iterator that fails silently?

Tags: lua, iterator, assert

I have a very simple problem with a simple iterator.

Let's say that I design a function, `files()`, that iterates over all the files in a folder:

```
for file in files("/path/to/folder") do
  print(file)
end
```

Now, this seems perfect, but there's a problem here: What if the the folder doesn't exist, or we don't have read permission to it?

How would we indicate such error?

One solution would be to have `files()` return `nil, "no read permission"` in this case. We'd then be able to wrap the call to `files()` inside `assert()`:

```
for file in assert(files("/path/to/folder")) do
  print(file)
end
```

This seemingly solves the problem. But this forces our users to always use `assert()`. What if the user doesn't care about errors? For this kind of users we'd want our `files()` to behave as if the folder is empty. But Lua --in case `files()` indicates error-- would try to call the returned `nil` and this will result in an error ("attempt to call a nil value").

So,

How can we design an iterator, `files()`, that would cater to both users that care about errors and users that don't?

If it's not possible, what alternative would you suggest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First: Instead of returning `nil` + error message consider raising an error in the `files` function (using `error`). This way you can't forget the `assert` call, and you won't get the confusing "attempt to call a nil value" error.

You could pass an extra boolean parameter to `files` when you don't want to raise errors -- you should return an empty function (`function() end`) instead of calling `error` in this case.

A more general approach is the following:

```
-- an iterator that immediately stops a for loop
local function dummy_iter() end

-- catch errors and skip for loop in that case
function iterpcall( g, ... )
  local ok, f, st, var = pcall( g, ... )
  if ok then
    return f, st, var
  else
    return dummy_iter
  end
end


for file in iterpcall( files, "/path/to/folder" ) do
  print( file )
  for line in iterpcall( io.lines, file ) do -- works for other iterators as well
    print( line )
  end
end
```

The implementation of `iterpcall` above only handles errors raised in the iterator *generator* (`files` or `io.lines`), not in the iterator function (`f`) itself. You would have to wrap `f` in a closure with a `pcall` to do that.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Indeed, once we ditch the idea that one function should behave in two different ways at the same time, everything becomes easier.

Answer (score 3):

There also question what you whant to do if you get error in the middle of iteration (e.g. access deny for subfolder with recurcive iteration). In this case assert does not help.

In this case I create 2 variant of iterators (inner and outer).

```
-- raise error
for file in files(...) do ... end

-- return error
files(...,function(file) ... end)
```

Or just create 2 different iterators.